# Missing numbers

Tags: pattern, visual, calculation-puzzle

The hexagon below is almost complete but there are 3 missing numbers. Try replace the question marks!

[image]

Hint

> starts at 0, ends at 12.

Hint2:

> 0 corresponds to 1.

Hint3

> It's a number sequence, starting with 0 and ends at 12(note: there are 12 different sections.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these the missing numbers:

> 42, 72, 110
>
>  [image]

The pattern would be:

> Start with 1 in the innermost upper-right box, then fill each sequential number into the clockwise-adjacent box in the same ring.
> On the 4th box of the ring, move to the adjacent outer ring box and continue filling in.
> Then, for each gray square, multiply by the previous index value.
>
> ```
> 1 x 0
> 2
> 3 x 2
> 4
> 5
> 6 x 5
> 7 x 6
> 8
> 9 x 8
> 10
> 11 x 10
> 12
> ```

A slightly different pattern would be:

> 210, 72, 110
> If you multiply by the previous box's value instead of the original number (7 x 30 instead of 7 x 6)

Comment: Yes, the 1st pattern is correct! The missing numbers are indeed 42, 72, 110. I thought of it like this though: 7^2-7, 9^2-9, 11^2-11. But obviously that gives the exact same answer :D So, well done!

Answer (score -1):

[image: diagram]

The sum of the numbers in the middle hexagon: 30+5+8+1=44

The sum of the inside hexagon: 4+6+2+0=12

The sum of the outer hexagon: 10+1+12+9=32

So the sum of the middle hexagon is equal to the sum of the inner and outer hexagons.

Comment: No, not the correct answer.. i'll add another hint today.